# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, I can't resolve it

Tags: java, hyperlink, native, opencl

I am trying to setup a program that uses Java and OpenCL. I am using JOCL's bindings for this. Here is the error I get when I build from Ant:

```
Error while loading native library "JOCL-linux-x86_64" with base name "JOCL"
    Operating system name: Linux
    Architecture         : amd64
    Architecture bit size: 64
    Stack trace:
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JOCL-linux-x86_64 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        ...
        ...
```

Here is my .bashrc setup:

```bash
export PATH=.:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin://home/djkashta/Desktop/bp-trunk/app/BlueprintCore/scripts:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/cuda/computeprof/bin:/home/djkashta/Desktop/bp-trunk/bundles/CopperShark/native/linux/2.6.28/x86_64/:/usr/java:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin:/usr/lib/jvm

export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23/jre/lib/amd64/libjsig.so

export JDK_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23
export ANT_HOME=/opt/apache-ant-1.7.1
```

I don't understand why I have this problem. I don't get this on my Ubuntu machine which is setup just like this RedHat machine. The `libJOCL-linux-x86_64.so` is present in one of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If I do which Java, I get: `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java`

Any ideas? I am stuck...

Comment: As a note about $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I always prefer to add a file into /etc/ld.so.conf.d and then run 'ldconfig'.

Comment: What's displayed if you print `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` before loading the library?

Comment: I get something I didn't expect, a directory within my application. Some code or some project settings I am not aware of probably set it to what it is: java.library.path: /home/<my_username>/Desktop/bp-trunk/app/BlueprintCore/nativelib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH and java.library.path are not the same, although they are similar. On the command line set -Djava.library.path to the place that your library is in.

or, even - System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")) just before loading the library - to see what it thinks the path is...

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to do a System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")). I did not realize my application was looking for my native libs in a different location. Now the error is gone! Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem - BTW - the difference between LD_LIBRARY_PATH and java.library.path is most obvious when the library that java loads has some dependent libraries that it must load in turn. The java.library.path will have no effect. Remember you can always load the library by hand yourself from an explicit location (but this is best reserved for more complex use cases)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but could someone explain me how exactly the issue was solved then, i.e. what should be added to the java.library.path to make it work? JOCL only contains a JAR file which probably contains these libraries somewhere deep within, but it's not clear to me at all which path to supply then.